# Predefined type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsExternalInit' is not defined or imported

Tags: c#-9.0

I have been having this issues while testing the new features of C# 9.0 with Visual Studio 2019 Preview. I was testing the init setter, but the compiler shows error with the message:

Error CS0518 Predefined type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsExternalInit' is not defined or imported. Below is the code  snippet that I've tried:

```cs
public class Book
{
     string ISBN { get; init; }
}
```

Answer (score 165, accepted):

This is a small bug in Visual Studio 2019 that hasn't been fixed yet. To solve this, you need to add a dummy class named `IsExternalInit` with the namespace `System.Runtime.CompilerServices` anywhere in your project. That will do it.

If writing a library it's best to make this class internal, as otherwise you can end up with two libraries both defining the same type.

```cs
    namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices
    {
          internal static class IsExternalInit {}
    }
```

**Edit** (November 16, 2020):

According to a reply I got from the Principle Developer Lead on C# Language Team, Jared Parsons, the issue above is not a bug. The compiler throws this error because we're compiling a .NET 5 code against older .NET Framework version. See his message below:

> Thanks for taking the time to file this feedback issue. Unfortunately
> this is not a bug. The `IsExternalInit` type is only included in the
> `net5.0` (and future) target frameworks. When compiling against older
> target frameworks you will need to manually define this type.

Link to the report on Visual Studio Developer Community: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1244809/error-cs0518-predefined-type-systemruntimecompiler.html

Comment: Is there a link to the bug report so we can known when it gets fixed?

Comment: @DavidLechner please see this link. Developer at Microsoft replied to my reporting. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1244809/error-cs0518-predefined-type-systemruntimecompiler.html

Comment: I still had my project configured for netstandard (even though i switched to version 9).  Was a silly mistake, but this answer certainly helped point that out.

Comment: Just thinking out loud - if it's not a bug, then why it is not in the documentation in the first place and why am I reading it on the StackOverflow :)

Comment: I'm getting this error even in a net5.0 project.... at random. Some days it builds, some days it doesn't... losing my mind.

Comment: I don't get it. Why are there language version and runtime version if a language feature is only available on a certain runtime? Isn't the C# language specification itself independent of the .NET runtime?

Comment: I also recieve this in Rider IDE by Jetbrains, so I don't know if it's an issue with vs.

Comment: Imho, it's better to wrap the code with `#if !NET5_0_OR_GREATER` `#endif`

Answer (score 8):

If you want to stay with .NET Core App 3.1, you will need to add the type like Kinin Roza explained in [in this bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1244809/error-cs0518-predefined-type-systemruntimecompiler.html).

However, if you change your `csproj` to have the `<TargetFramework>` set to `net5.0`, it will solve your problem as this type is only defined in 5.0.

Here's my sample Console app `csproj` file.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: I had this issue event with .Net5.0 , not sure why

Comment: The solution works with .Net 7.0.  After adding    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework> the problem resolved automatically.